# python convert a string to arguments list

Tags: python, eval

Can I convert a string to arguments list in python?

```
def func(**args):
    for a in args:
        print a, args[a]

func(a=2, b=3)

# I want the following work like above code
s='a=2, b=3'
func(s)
```

I know:

list can, just use *list, but list can't have an element like: a=2

and eval can only evaluate expression

which would be like:

```
def func2(*args):
    for a in args:
        print a

list1=[1,2,3]
func2(*list1)
func2(*eval('1,2,3'))
```

Comment: Something like [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args) should do it. have a look at how to call `parse_args()` with arguments.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could massage the input string into a dictionary and then call your function with that, e.g.

```
>>> x='a=2, b=3'
>>> args = dict(e.split('=') for e in x.split(', '))
>>> f(**args)
a 2
b 3
```

Comment: First seen this syntax. Thank you. I don't know why `tuple(e.split('=')) for e in x.split(', ')` will cause syntax error, isn't it an argument of dict()? Is there an explain about this rule?

Comment: @AylwynLake: It is a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) which in turn is a generalized form of [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: But a and b are of strings and not integers. How do I convert them to integers?

Comment: @zeeshankhan You could massage the dictionary a bit further and apply `int` to all values, e.g. `args = {k: int(v) for k, v in args.items()}`

Answer (score 14):

You want a *dictionary*, not an 'argument list'. You also would be better off using [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to evaluate *just* Python literals:

```
from ast import literal_eval

params = "{'a': 2, 'b': 3}"
func(**literal_eval(params))
```

Before you go this route, make sure you've explored other options for marshalling options first, such as `argparse` for command-line options, or JSON for network or file-based transfer or persistence.

Comment: +1 but this solution may not be applicable in case the `a=2, b=3` string is user input (e.g. from a configuration file or the like); you'd rather not allow evaluating arbitrary Python code. :-}

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: The OP seemed to be looking for the equivalent of `args  "(1, 2, 3)"` and `func2(*literal_eval(args))` here; e.g. something that would produce the right python structure to apply to call.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I mean as Frerich Raabe said. I want to read from config file of tables, then use sqlalchemy to auto generate tables. when processing Column('id', Integer, primary_key = True). Then ask this question.

Comment: @AylwynLake: And you cannot use a configuration format that lets you specify the id, type and other options as separate entries?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The config file like, tablename1, id|integer|primary_key, name|varchar(20)|, age|integer|\n tablename2, id|serial|primary_key, user1|integer|ForeignKey, user2|integer|ForeignKey, relation|varchar(20)|\n ... I split the lines then compose a table. But can't figure out how to construct primary_key=True

Comment: @AylwynLake: You are always free to further process that format. Falling back to `literal_eval` or `eval` is, to me, giving up. You are already parsing that format, how hard would it be to add a little more parsing? Frerich's answer shows one such parse method.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: `print literal_eval("String(20)")` raise ValueError, `print eval("String(20)")` output `VARCHAR(20)`. Is there a compromise method?

Comment: Good point, but one may actually want an [argument_list](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#calls). I colleague wished to parse a command line argument value as if it were an `argument_list` (without spaces), and rejected the [dict_display](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) format.

Comment: @naxa: this *produces* an argument list. There is no dict display here.

Comment: sorry if I was unclear, I tried to mean the `{` `:` `}` related *format* by "dict_display". If you have a string like `x=1,c=2` etc. (I attempted to refer it to as "argument_list", meaning the format primarily), which let's assume you have no control over, I think you cannot use `ast.literal_eval`, that's what I wished to say.

Comment: @naxa: right, no, that's not a Python literal, you'll have to parse that directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the string as an argument list directly in an call to `eval`, e.g.

```
def func(**args):
    for a in args:
        print( a, args[a])

s = 'a=2, b=3'

eval('func(' + s + ')')
>>>b 3
>>>a 2
```

Note that `func` needs to be in the namespace for the eval call to work like this.