# how to convert string into argument?

Tags: python

While applying some external module method to a class I need to be able to pass different pairs of `arg = 'value'` to the function, like:

```
Ad.nodes.get(id_ = '11974312')
```

How to pass dicts or tuples to the function, so that it recognises `'id_'` (string) as `id_` (argument) in
`('id_', '11974312')` (tuple) or `{'id_':'11974312'}` (dictionary) ?

Basically, I just need to get `id_` out of `'id_'`

For your reference, I am trying to use neomodel module for neo4j graph db.

Comment: could you provide an example of your code so far and maybe some examples of what you've attempted?

Comment: This answers your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263839/python-convert-a-string-to-arguments-list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python convert a string to arguments list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263839/python-convert-a-string-to-arguments-list)

Comment: literal_eval is what you need

Comment: didn't you just asked this question here [translate string into function argument](//stackoverflow.com/q/54627773)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [translate string into function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54627773/translate-string-into-function-argument)

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for the ** operator.

Example:

```
kwargs = {'first': 3, 'second': 6}

def add(first, second):
    return first + second

print(add(**kwargs) == 9)
```

This will print `True`. When you apply `**` to a `dict` argument, it will be decomposed into keyword arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The argument name can be read as string using inspect.signature(function name).parameters.keys() where function name is a name of function, which argument need to be read as string

Example:

```
    import inspect, itertools 
dictionary={'id':'David','ip':'11.1.1.20'}
def func(id,ip):
                    func_argument = list(inspect.signature(func).parameters.keys() )
                    print(func_argument)
                    #Print the value from dic for each argument which is key in dict
                    for i in func_argument:
                        print(dictionary[i])                    
func(id=100,ip=200)
```